# Help understanding 'personally I'm disappointed' vs. 'I'm personally disappointed'

Tags: adverbs, word-order

Today I encountered a sentence:

"I suppose that makes sense, but personally I'm disappointed."

Normally, I only see structure adj+adv or adv+adj in middle of sentence. In addition, I do see sentence with 'personally' in the start of the sentence, and then a comma separates it with the main part of the sentence. But I have never see any thing like this.

Could you please explain why we can use 'personally' like this in a sentence? What is the general rule ?

BTW, can I re-write the question like this: " I suppose that makes sense, but I'm personally disappointed."?

Comment: If you change *we can use personally* to *we can personally use*, it will sound much better.

Comment: @DamkerngT. - I edited the question to be more clear.  I believe your suggested edit would have changed the intent.

Comment: If I am not wrong, personally is the adverb of the sentence " I'm disappointed". In this case better use a comma after it. Or if you use it at the end of sentence, use comma before it. It's not suggested to use it in the mid position.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the edit, @MrWonderful. I understand the OP now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Traditional grammar would say that *personally* here modifies the verb, but actually what it modifies is the entire clause, in the same way *frankly* or *actually* or *as a matter of fact* or *moreover* or *however* would: it's equivalent to something like *It's my personal opinion that*.

Consequently, it may be placed at a number of places in the sentence:

> 1) Personally I'm disappointed.
>   2) I'm disappointed personally.
>   3) I personally am disappointed.
>   4) I'm personally disappointed.

(The last two, however, are ambiguous.  In 3), *personally* may be understood to modify *I*, meaning your objection is only yours, not that of any organization you represent. And in 4) *personal* may be understood to modify *disappointed*, in the sense that you have experienced some personal loss rather than having an ethical or practical objection.)

As for the presence or absence of one or more commas: this is a matter of stylistic choice, not any sort of "rule". In very brief clauses like this one there's really no structural complexity to unravel, and commas would serve primarily to indicate whether the comma-bracketed matter is to be regarded as an integral part of the clause or a "supplement"—a parenthetical observation.

Comment: I don't think 3 is ambiguous. To me it's quite clear that it is equivalent to 1. 4, however, I agree is ambiguous. Concerning your note on commas, however, note that by simply adding a comma to 2, it changes its meaning: "I'm disappointed, personally."

Comment: As a native speaker, (2) looks really weird to me.  Maybe you wanted a comma between disappointed and personally?

Comment: Could you explain the use of "Consequently" at the beginning of your second paragraph ? (-:

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I see that might be considered wrong with the sentence in question is a potentially-missing comma.  Personally, I would have written:

> "I suppose that makes sense, but personally, I'm disappointed."

The two thoughts divided by the 'but' could also be swapped while the sentence retained the same meaning, like this:

> "Personally, I'm disappointed, but I suppose that makes sense."

This would create the form you indicated you *have* seen before.

Both are equivalent in meaning -- merely a difference in style separates them.

Comment: sorry because I cannot up vote you yet

Comment: That is OK.  I'm glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 3):

It's a colloquialism. It can be taken to be an abbreviation for "but personally **speaking,** I'm disappointed". Don't attempt to apply standard scholarly English grammar to dialect and colloquial speech.

If you accept that the adverb modifies **be** ("personally I am"), then it could also be interpreted as poetic speech: "quickly I run", "deftly I type".

It is *incorrect* to change the word order, because that changes the binding of the adverb, from **be** ("personally be"), to **disappoint** ("personally disappoint"). In turn, this changes the meaning from "My personal position is that I am disappointed" to "My position is that I am disappointed in a personal way".

Comment: I agree with your last sentence as the correct distinction, but I would argue that neither are "incorrect." There should, however, be a comma after "personally" in the first form: Personally, I'm disappointed.

Answer (score 2):

"Personally, xxx" - It means that xxx is just my personal opinion, and other people might see things differently. "Personally, I am disappointed" - I feel disappointed, but I admit that someone else in the same situation might not be disappointed.

"I am personally disappointed" - this is a *very* strong statement. Something disappointed me, and I take it personally. I'm not going to forget this soon, and it may have consequences for the person that disappointed me.